# How to add a gem in development group from a Rails engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-engines

Im developing a [Rails engine](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) that includes 3 dependencies:

*gemspec*

```
s.add_dependency "rswag-api"
s.add_dependency "rswag-ui"
s.add_dependency "rswag-specs"
```

My problem is I want the third gem (`rswag-specs`) available in my host application **under development environment only**. Normally, in a Rails app would do this:

*Gemfile*

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rswag-specs'
end
```

I need to do something similar from my gem instead.

#### UPDATE

`s.add_development_dependency` will not install the gem in `group :development`

[image]

Comment: Can you not add it to the Gemfile of the engine?

Comment: Gemfile.lock lists gems for all groups.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
s.add_development_dependency 'rswag-specs'
```

This is directly from the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#other-gem-dependencies)